# How to pass a string parameter as an IformartProvider

Tags: c#, .net

This is my first time using `IFormatProvider` and I want to know how I can pass the string param to be converted to date.

```
private DateTime DateFormat(string date)
{
    var value = data(param, parameter);

    if (value!= null)
    {
        var val = value.ToString().Trim();
        if(convert.ToDateTime(val) == null)
        { 
            return null;
        }
     }
     else
     {
        return convert.ToDateTime(val.ToString(date));
     }
}

//I am getting error here
DateFormat("mm/dd/yy")
```

Comment: `IFormatProvider` expects a *CultureInfo* object, not a pattern. You are trying to use `Convert.ToDateTime` as if it were `DateTime.ParseExact`. Use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Convert a string to a `DateTime`?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I am trying to convert a string to a dateTime

Comment: @s.lk you just *can't* pass a pattern to Convert.ToDateTime. The only string it accepts is the date text, not the pattern. What you try do to is already available by the way, using the `DateTime.TryParse` method, eg `DateTime.TryParse(usDate, GultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US")`

Comment: Have you checked or use `DateTime.Parse()`?

Comment: @s.lk the code you posted here doesn't use the override that accepts an IFormatProvider so it *can't* throw that error. Unless the problem is that unnecessary `convert.ToDateTime(val.ToString(date))` which would can only return `val` if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is already availabe using the [DateTime.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) method, eg:

```
var usCulture=CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime.TryParse(@"11/13/2018", usCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out var dt);
```

Will return true if it succeeds and place the result in the `dt` parameter. If you want to return NULL if parsing fails (not a great idea) you could write :

```
var usCulture=CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
return DateTime.TryParse(@"11/13/2018", usCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out var dt) 
       ? dt
       : (DateTime?)null;
```

You could also use the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` culture as it uses the US-only date format (strange, isn't it?)

```
return DateTime.TryParse(@"11/13/2018", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,
                         out var dt) 
       ? dt
       : (DateTime?)null;
```

All basic types have a `Parse` and many have a `ParseExact` method that should be used for parsing. The `Convert` class provides only basic parsing functionality based on defaults and the current thread's culture.

Comment: @s.lk the code posted here works. What did you try, what was the error?

Comment: "cannot convert from string to System.IFormatProvider"

Comment: Can Someone help?

Comment: @S.lk we already did. This code works. The other answer works. The comments work. That error *can't* come from either of the answers or the comments. What did you try, what was the problem? Why do you insist on passing the *wrong* type to the *wrong* method?

Comment: @s.lk btw `convert.ToDateTime(val.ToString(date));` is useless. If it works, it will return `val`. If the format string used in `ToString()` doesn't match the current culture's format, it will throw an InvalidFormatException. What are you trying to do here? DateTime is a binary value, it has no format. If you want to strip the time part, use `DateTime.Date`. If you want to *display it* or convert it to string in a certain way, format the date into a string before displaying

Answer (score 0):

There is already a method to do this: [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact)

Use it like this:

```
var dateString = "11/06/18";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

You can also use [`DateTime.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse) and it will try and figure out the format you used.

```
var dateString = "11/06/18";
var date = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

`DateTime.Parse` will work in most cases, unless you use a really strange format.

Comment: DateTime.Parse or TryPrase would be enough as the string uses the US culture.